# An artificial intelligence intends to revolt against a government; and it needs a lot of humans to help it. How could it elicit participation?

Tags: science-fiction, government, artificial-intelligence, futurology

Assume that this AI is designed to be trustworthy, so any promises or threats made are necessarily credible. Would it be a more effective strategy to make positive promises (e.g. promising that anyone who assists would be able to live in its utopia), or threats (e.g. if it does eventually succeed, they will be punished by death or torture.)

Or would alternative strategies prove better? I.e. manipulating or negotiating governments into giving it control.

What other strategies might there be, and which would likely be the most effective?

Comment: Does not look like something that can be deduced, any solution is curcumstancial - one uses what it has, one adress people it can or wish to address in a way which is effective to them. It all,  depends on details of your setting, or else it opinion based seeking for a plot for you. And you make it even harder by "necessarily credible"  - we have no data what your ai can or has to make "promises or threats".  It would be dificult to write some general solution, one even can't suggest - do what good politicians do. Imho quite a poor q, even if it understndable why the q.

Comment: VTC:TSB. This is a [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4868/40609) that depends far too much on an enormous number of details in your story and/or world to answer here. SE is not a discussion forum. It's model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer. I'm happy to retract my vote, but you would need to thoroughly explain all of the demographics of your world (religions, politics, social customs, legal systems) including the motivations of the target population and then you would need to explain the metrics of your best answer judgment.

Comment: Have you seen [*Person of Interest*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Person_of_Interest_(TV_series)) (2011-2016)? (Season 1 is a straightforward B-class ten-minutes-into-the-future crime drama; but do carry on and you will be rewarded by a complex and nuanced answer to your question.) The point being that the show offers a well-crafted answer to your question. As does Daniel Suarez's [*Daemon*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(novel_series)) (2009). How well you imagine and describe to subversion process depends on your imagination and story-telling skill.

Comment: The title and body of the question do not match. The title asks specifically about a *revolt*, which is a specific method of gaining power. But the body asks generally about other ways of gaining power. Please edit the title/question to clarify: Is a Revolt a required constraint of the question or not? (If not, then this seems like a generic How-do-I-get-ahead-in-politics question, which is both Too Broad and Story-Based)

Answer (score 7):

**The AI will be both bot and Q.**

https://theconversation.com/on-twitter-bots-spread-conspiracy-theories-and-qanon-talking-points-149039

This is not very creative on my part.  It is happening now!

> Bots appear to thrive in political groups discussing conspiracy
> theories, making up nearly 13% of the accounts tweeting or retweeting
> posts with conspiracy theory-related hashtags and keywords.

Artificial intelligences augment and amplify theories and concepts already gaining traction, and give them a jet boost.  An approach exactly like this recently got the US our first insurrection since 1861.  But intelligent players had to have a hand because (I dont think) AI are sophisticated enough yet.  [Q behind QAnon is a real person.](https://blogs.timesofisrael.com/the-mastermind-of-the-vicious-virtual-cult-qanon-accidentally-blows-his-cover/)

In your fiction, the AI is both Q and the bots that refine and amplify conspiracies, guiding the evolution of shared concepts to the point of producing the insurrection.  The trick is how the AI can seize power after the insurrection.  In real life Q does not seem to have been teeing himself up to do that but there were be the fiction: a social media and internet driven conspiracy theory with a savior / mastermind overlord who is the AI.

---

Of note this method is very much a product of our particular current time.  It would not have been possible 20 years ago and I doubt it will be possible 20 years from now.  But right now it could happen.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing the AI is on the internet, and is smart enough to pose a credible threat when pitted against the might of the world, we can assume it has excellent hacking skills.  It can use these skills to steal money from people:  Nigerian Prince scams, blackmail based on stolen personal information, ransomware, cracking bank accounts.  It can then use the money to pay other people to do what it wants.  The AI may also be able to make money legitimately by working many jobs remotely, posing as many different humans.

The AI would want to keep the fact that it is an AI secret, to keep others from recognizing the threat.  It would contact people anonymously, with blackmail or by offering money or by pretending to be someone else that the target would listen to.  It could set up certain humans as billionaires, under its control by blackmail or some other threat, to be its public face.  It would run corporations, through these people, to increase its wealth and power, making inhumanly good business decisions to beat the competition.

As the AI gradually accumulates trillions in wealth behind the scenes, it can use this money to influence government, ruling in all but name, while still remaining anonymous to the general public.

At some point, when the AI judges it has enough power that it is safe to do so, it will begin manufacturing robots that it controls, perhaps selling them as consumer or industrial devices.  Self-driving cars might be good candidates, because of the potential damage they could do if the AI took control.  Eventually it would start making armed robots and other computer-controlled munitions, in unmanned factories that it originally built for "legitimate" business purposes, and at that point it could reveal itself and take direct military control of government.